# Google BigQuery error: Out of buffer space (error code: invalid)

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm using `Google Bigquery` `user-defined functions` to flatten and transpose nested fields of daily data.

All data processing works well except one day data. When I process that day data, the Google Biequery returns the following error status (the error is thrown by user-defined function):

```
Errors:
script: Out of buffer space (error code: invalid)
Job ID    XXX:XXXXX
Start Time    Mar 21, 2016, 4:39:42 PM
End Time    Mar 21, 2016, 4:39:48 PM
Destination Table    XXX:XXXXX
Write Preference    Append to table
Allow Large Results    true
Flatten Results    false
```

The raw data size for that day is about 1GB, there's no problem to process other days data which is much larger than that day's data.

Does anyone have any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem:

This error is not a Google BigQuery error, this error is a JavaScript error thrown from UDF functions.

I have very long strings in some nest fields, and I concatenate strings from these fields, these long strings caused the JavaScript `out of buffer space` error.

By filtering out the supper long string fields fix the problem